# Solving a constrained linear system of equations using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to solve a linear equation `(AX=b)` where `A` is an 8x8 matrix, and `X` and `b` are 8x1 vectors.
`X` can be expressed by `X=[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]`. However, I have the following 3 constraints that I need to respect:

```
1) 0.5*(y1 + y2) = 0
2) 0.5*(x3 + x4) = 0
3) 0.5*(y3 + y4) = 0
```

First, I tried to integrate the constraints into matrix `A` (which became of shape 11x8) and multiplied both parts of the equation by the pseudo-inverse of `A` to get the solution `X`, but the solution I found with this method still did not satisfy the constraints.
So, I created an optimzation problem in python using scipy. However, I think I am doing something wrong (probably in my objective function) since the solver message states that the optimization was terminated successful and the found solution does indeed satisfy the constraints, but when I multiply the matrix `A` by the found solutions for the vector `X`, I do not get the values of vector `b`. So, the system is not being solved.

I tried the following code :

```
A = np.array([
    [-261.60,  11.26,      0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0],
    [   4.07, -12.75,      0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0],
    [    0.0,    0.0,  -158.63,  -5.65,     0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0],
    [    0.0,    0.0,    -2.81, -12.14,     0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0],
    [    0.0,    0.0,      0.0,    0.0, -265.99,  19.29,     0.0,    0.0],
    [    0.0,    0.0,      0.0,    0.0,   12.59, -12.34,     0.0,    0.0],
    [    0.0,    0.0,      0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0, -166.25, -12.63],
    [    0.0,    0.0,      0.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,   -8.40, -11.14]
])

b = np.array([
     -6.95,
     16.35,
     -0.96,
     16.35,
     19.19,
    -15.85,
    -12.36,
    -15.63]).reshape(-1, 1)

def objective_function(x):
    return np.sum((np.dot(A, x) - b)**2)

def constraints(x):
    return np.array([
        0.5*(x[1] + x[3]),  # 0.5*(y1 + y2) = 0
        0.5*(x[4] + x[6]),  # 0.5*(x3 + x4) = 0
        0.5*(x[5] + x[7])   # 0.5*(y3 + y4) = 0
    ])


cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraints}
options = {'disp': True, 'verbose': 4}

res = optimize.minimize(objective_function, np.zeros(8), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, options={'disp': True})

x_optimized = res.x

# Checking if solution was found
print(np.matmul(A, x_optimized))
```

At the end, the output of `np.matmul(A, x_optimized)` is :

```
[ 0.01723619  0.00041891  0.01781721 -0.00034223  0.0113301  -0.00848171
  0.01008367  0.00781168]
```

However, I was expecting the same values as vector b if the system was actually solved :

```
[ -6.95  16.35  -0.96  16.35  19.19 -15.85 -12.36 -15.63]
```

Comment: How do you know that a solution close to `b` that satisfies the constraints exists?

Comment: Also, what are the meaning of your constraints? You have both x and y listed in your constraints and the numbers don't match the indices you used.

Comment: @jared thanks for your response. X contains the variables x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 in that order. The constraints are used to find a solution where the middle points of y1 and y2, x3 and x4, and y3 and y4 do not move. As for how do I know there is a solution, i am assuming there is one. Is there a way to force the optimization problem try to minimize the objective function to 0 and otherwise it fails? I am not sure if I set up the optimization problem correctly.

Comment: I am not convinced that a solution exists. The minimizer won't fail because you didn't get 0 since it did its job and found the smallest value it could. If you want, check the optimizer function using the value the optimizer found and print out if the result isn't close to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your constraints are linear you can put them all in a linear equation.

You can use least squares solution, if the system has exact solution you will get it, otherwise you will get as close as possible.

```
AC = np.zeros([3, A.shape[1]])
bC = np.zeros((3, 1))
AC[0][[1, 3]] = 0.5 # 0.5 * (y1 + y2) = 0
AC[1][[4, 6]] = 0.5 # 0.5 * (x3 + x4) = 0
AC[2][[5, 7]] = 0.5 # 0.5 * (y3 + y4) = 0

# Solve the augmented system
A = np.vstack([A, AC])
b = np.vstack([b, bC])
x, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)
```